# Powershell remove inside square brackets

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I have files with these names:

```
Aaron Wilde - Awaken.mp3
Aaron Wilde - Heroes Collide [Hybrid Orchestral, Action Music].mp3
Aaron Wilde - Into The Fire [Hybrid Orchestral, Heroic, Uplifting Music].mp3
Aaron Wilde - Legacy [Hybrid Orchestral, Vocal, Heroic].mp3
Aaron Wilde - Miracles [Fantasy, Emotional Music].mp3
Aaron Wilde - Together We Rise [Heroic, Orchestral, Battle Music].mp3
```

I want to rename files without bracket in filenames. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
 get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { move-item -literalpath $_.name $_.name.replace("``[*``]","")}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. String `.Replace` method is for literal strings, use `-replace` operator.
2. Instead of `` use `\` and `.*` instead of `*`:
   `.` means any symbol, `*` means 0 or more occurrences

---

```
move-item -literalpath $_.name ($_.name -replace '\[.*\]', '')
```